# How to "rollout" Kubernetes Deployment to a previous revision using "rollingUpdate" strategy?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using K8s [Deployment](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments) API. When applying update I use RollingUpdate strategy and works perfectly.

However when I do "rollout undo", k8s kills all of the pods and create new ones, i.e. the rollback is disruptive.

Is there a way to configure "rollout undo" to use a RollingUpdate (to previous version) as well?

Comment: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#rollback-to is rollback-to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Rollback should use the same strategy you specified (i.e. RollingUpdate). The behavior you saw isn't expected. Can you provide the configuration (yaml/json) of your `Deployment`?

Comment: I retest it on current, 1.2.2, version the "Undo" works with RollingUpdate strategy.

Comment: Also retested on 1.2.0 and 1.2.1 and work as expected. Sorry. It seems like I was wrong in my test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to roll back to a previous version, you may first get the history of your deployment by this

```
kubectl rollout history deployment/<deployment-name>
```

Then, using the following you may roll back to a specific revision

```
kubectl rollout undo deployment/<deployment-name> --to-revision=<revision-number>
```

Finally, you may verify the current state of the deployment using this

```
kubectl rollout status deployment/<deployment-name>
```